# solve 6 equations with 6 unknowns Gauss

Tags: gaussian-elimination

I have been using the finite-difference method and get 6 equations with 6 unknowns.  Now I want to solve them using Gauss' method but I don't know how.  I can solve them with math-lab but I want to learn Gauss' method:

```
-96.51*T1+0.30.3*T2=-2051.3
0.3*T1-151.2*T2+0.3*T3+0.*T4=-2250
0.6*T2-43.62*T3+0.6*T5=-1852.61
0.3*T2-150.6*t4+0.3*T5=-2250
2*T3+T4-4*T5+T6=0
0.3*T5-42.72*T6=-1852.61
```

Answer (score 1):

Gaussian elimination is adding multiples of an equation in the system to other equations in the system until each equation has only one variable left on the left hand side. If you want to learn Gaussian elimination, please google it or look it up on Wikipedia before posting here.

Comment: thanks for your help, but really i had watch some youtube videos about Gaussian elimination but i cant solve those equations

Comment: The first and last equations have only two variables. You can rearrange them to get an expression for one variable in terms of the other, then substitute into the four remaining equations. You repeat these steps until you've solved for every variable.